# PHP import/export entities to XML, XLS, CSV…

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, mapping, export, entity

Is there any PHP library that enables to import and/or export objects (actually Doctrine 2 entities) to various formats like XML, XLS, CSV, etc.

What I'm looking for is a generic semi-automatic solution (not a specific Excel library for example): i.e. the only thing to configure is the mapping between the file format and the entities.

Like Doctrine 2 maps objects to DB schemas, that would be a library that maps objects to file  formats.

Answer (score 1):

theres should be lots out there, but i only can think of one right now, [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

on its features page it says:

"Output your spreadsheet object to different file formats"

- Excel 2007 (spreadsheetML)
- IFF8 (Excel 97 and higher)
- PHPExcel Serialized Spreadsheet
- CSV (Comma Separated Values)
- HTML
- PDF

Comment: Yeah that's what I used before, but I'm looking for a solution that exports objects automagically, we me telling which fields to export for example. In other terms, a library focused on objects (or data) rather than file format.